# How do I see old fashion screen with text?

Tags: fedora, grub, plymouth, bootsplash

I am trying to remove the splash screen or whatever that is called in Fedora 34 but I am unable because I am still seeing the following every time I reboot:

[image]

I have tried the following:

- Change the default Plymouth theme (https://fedoramagazine.org/howto-change-the-plymouth-theme/)

  ```
  sudo plymouth-set-default-theme text -R
  ```
- Edited the GRUB config file and "disabled" Plymouth

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/default/grub 
  // "rhgb quiet" from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX
  ```

Any other ideas? What I am missing here?

Comment: are you booting with the new ramdisk? The `-R` flag will rebuild the initrd, but probably only the latest. If you're booting an older version, it will likely be unchanged. Also - it's not a permanent solution - but - pressing ESC while seeing the boot screen should show the text as well.

Comment: @rudib how can I check whether I am booting with the new ramdisk or I am using an older version?

Comment: you should see the available kernel and ramdisk images with `ls /boot`. And `uname -a` will give you the kernel version you're running right now. The ramdisk version should be the same as the kernel version (pretty sure it wouldn't work with another version). P.S.: Make sure your boot partition is mounted when regenerating (made that mistake once)!

Comment: also, editing `/etc/default/grub` itself does nothing to your `grub.cfg` that is read at boot time. You have to regenerate the config: `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grubby` to add and delete commandline arguments to be passed to the kernel. You can choose to target only the current kernel or ALL kernels.

You appear to want to enable the kernel messages produced during a boot. To enable this, update the current kernel, as the root user, by doing:

```
kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r)"
grubby --update-kernel ${kernel} --remove-args="rhgb quiet"
```

The `grubby` manpages note:

> If the ALL argument is used in lieu of a specific kernel, the variable GRUB_CMD‐LINE_LINUX in '/etc/default/grub' is updated with the latest kernel argument list, unless the --no-etc-grub-update option is used.

Comment: this worked excellent!

Comment: I always had text boot. After updating to FC36, the boot is in text mode, but at the end it shows me a black text console but with an underscore only: no prompt login! I have to switch to the second text console to be able to login.